# Multidimensional array sort by time - not working

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, datetime, usort

I'm trying to sort a multidimensional array by date. This is the current output of my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 07/08/19
            [title] => Some Title here
            [category] => Food
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 07/09/19
            [title] => Example here
            [category] => Sports
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 06/12/19
            [title] => Some title here as well
            [category] => Other
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 08/2/19
            [title] => Nothing to see here
            [category] => Sports
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 02/29/18
            [title] => Testing title here
            [category] => Sports
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [weekOf] => 07/16/19
            [title] => Test Test
            [category] => Food
        )
)
```

Here is the function I have. I stripped out alot of the code the code to make it easier to read the question. The date is a string that I'm combining together and converting.

```
<?php
    public function docs(){
        //Removed unnessary code here for question purposes
        foreach($files as $file) {
            //Removed unnessary code here for question purposes

            //The date is a string that I'm converting into a date
            $date = $month . '/' . $day . '/' . $year;
            $newDate = strtotime($date); 
            $formatedDate = date('M/d/Y', $newDate);


            $rows[] = [
                'date' => $date,     
                'title' => $title, 
                'category' => $category,    
            ];


        }

        // Sorting array by time (DESC ORDER)
        usort($rows, function($firstItem, $secondItem) {
            $timeStamp1 = strtotime($firstItem['time']);
            $timeStamp2 = strtotime($secondItem['time']);
            return $timeStamp2 - $timeStamp1;
        });

        //more code here

    }
```

Comment: You have `'date' => $date,`, but then do try to use `$firstItem['time']`.  You should be getting "undefined index" warnings about that.

Comment: Also, maybe store date as a timestamp in the array and format it when needed?

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I'm been looking at this code for too long, can't believe I missed that. That fixed it for me. Thanks again Patrick.

Comment: @hisusu32 You can delete this one as it is typo that probably not help future users